# How to setup multiple camera modes flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, camera

I have a situation where I have to a have a few different sized "cameras" to send over a netstream depending on if its a desktop or mobile connected. Here's how I have it setup:

```
protected var nearCam:Camera;
protected var nearCamForMobile:Camera;

nearCam = Camera.getCamera();
nearCam.setMode(385,240,10);
nearCam.setQuality(0,0);
//this is the cam I want to display on the near Side to show the user themselves.
near_video.attachCamera(nearCam);


//If a mobile user connects, I want to send them this resolution/aspect ratio of a camera so i'm just setting up this Camera but not showing it anywhere.         
nearCamForMobile = Camera.getCamera();
nearCamForMobile.setMode(480,800,10);
nearCamForMobile.setQuality(0,0);
```

So when a mobile user connected I'd just swap the camera that's attached to the netstream to the mobile one so it looks good on their phone and not all stretched.

```
if(isFarMobile)
{
    sendStream.attachCamera(nearCamForMobile);
}
else
{
    sendStream.attachCamera(nearCam);
}
```

Now on to my problem....

If i do JUST the nearCamForMobile and send that to the mobile versaion it looks great on the phone and it's not stretched. but then obviously its 480x800 resolution looks stretched on the desktop version which is a 385x240 video box. So if i do just the nearCam it looks great on the desktop but then it looks stretched on the mobile....

So what im curious is why Cant I do both vars the way I showed above, display the nearCam, and then have the nearCamForMobile waiting to be sent when i need it to?

Can you only have one camera mode setup at a time? Any ideas how I could do this? On the mobile version its setup so the user is holding the phone in potrait and its 840x480. The desktop site looks best when its like a widescreen video.

In the end I'm basically trying to figure out how to have 2 camera vars with 2 resolutions. Display 1 on the near side and attach the other to the netstream in a situation where the far is a mobile client. (I know how to figure out if the far is mobile, im not worried about that part)

I just need to be able to transmit a resolution/aspect ratio that looks good for a mobile client. which happens to be in a different aspect ratio than the desktop cleint.

Comment: Am I reading this right - you want to capture in one resolution but display in another?

Comment: 2 resolutions. Display 1 on the near side and attach the other to the netstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done.  Check out this line specifically from the docs :

> "Multiple calls to the getCamera() method reference the same camera
>   driver. Thus, if your code contains code like firstCam:Camera =
>   getCamera() and secondCam:Camera = getCamera(), both firstCam and
>   secondCam reference the same camera, which is the user's default
>   camera."

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera()

So in other words, as soon as you get one, any subsequent get attempts will just be creating another pointer to the same object.  Thus, you have two variables with a pointer to the same object. Setting a property on that pointer sets it to both.

Make sense?

Sorry for the bad news  :\

Comment: (if you ask me, it should be static in that case, but whatev)  :P

Comment: You'll have to pick a resolution.  Can you go with the wide format and make the app a landscape app (and just shrink the video much smaller if the phone is in portrait orientation)?

Comment: I will I plan on picking a resoltuion soon, just wanted to leave this open just a tad longer to see if anyone might have any ideas how I might solve this. I hate to compromise on the design, It looks best when it's fullscreen. I can't force users to use landscape, some tablets and phones have cameras in different locations that seem natural to have the phone/tablet in portrait, or landscape. So It's up to the user to decide which orientation they want. I just wanted to have it looking good even if its sending to someone using it in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flash Builder 4.5, you can check whether or not you are accessing a mobile Camera by calling for CameraUI instead of Camera. You can check which type of camera you have by coding it like this:

```
if(CameraUI.isSupported)
{
    //Mobile camera
}
else
{
    //Desktop camera
}
```

You can find more information at this link: http://www.flex-tutorial.fr/2010/09/07/air-android-prendre-des-photos-videos-avec-cameraui/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's not really what im asking. sorry if its unclear. I'm not having an issue with checking if im sending to a mobile client. But I'm basically trying to figure out how to have 2 camera vars with 2 resolutions. Display 1 on the near side and attach the other to the netstream.

Comment: I should look into it, but I really don't have the time right now to do so. But i'm guessing you want to have some sort of omegle/chatroulette equivalent here, do you not? :)

Comment: I'm already done building it. I'm just putting finishing touches on a mobile app. Just having an issue with the resolution fitting the setup I have on the mobile interface.

Comment: I would take the highest resolution of the two and then try compressing the footage locally rather than sending it compressed :)